# Eclipse RCP application unable to find companion shared library in MAC

Tags: macos, eclipse-rcp

We are developing a rcp application using eclipse and we finally have a stable version ready for release. The application works fine when I run it in my system.

But, when we try to upload the application and download it using a link and try to run the application, we are getting an error "The application was unable to locate its companion shared library".

The problem is that if I generate the build and run the application in the same machine or a different machine, it works fine. It only happens when I download it and try to launch.

However, only when i try run the .app file, the above mentioned error appears. If I open the .app file and launch the unix executable, it works fine.

But, I would like to know how I can fix the issue so that I can run from the app file.

Comment: How are you building this RCP? A RCP built using maven + tycho for macOS should run without problems.

Comment: Yeah we are using maven + Tycho and it is running fine. The problem occurs only when we download it and the system prompts for permission since it is from internet. I am assuming it is a permission issue.

Comment: I think you may need to use the XCode 'codesign' to sign the app with a Apple supplied developer certificate. For macOS 10.15 (Catalina) you may also need to [notarize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution?language=objc) your app

Comment: @greg-449 I am trying to follow your advice. I have installed Xcode and I am not sure how to sign the app which I have already built and kept ready. Can you point me to some documentation

Comment: Sorry I don't know exactly what is required, I have just know that Eclipse themselves needed to do this. The Apple developer help should cover this.